# sql query for masking only 1st 5 char of value

Tags: sql, string, oracle

i need your help in creating the below query for "I have a column called  'A' with 10 digits in length
I also have a column called 'B'

```
   A                                   B
1234567890                           SAM
2345678912                           HELLO
7364557382                           MORNING
```

I want to mask column A and replace the first 5 digits with column B.

Post masking :

```
SAM   67890  (with 2 spaces)
HELLO78912 
MORNI557382
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions:

```
select t.*, rpad(b, 5, ' ') || substr(a, 6) res
from mytable t
```

If `a` is a number, you can explictly cast it first:

```
select t.*, rpad(b, 5, ' ') || substr(to_char(a), 6) res
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RPAD( B, 5, ' ' ) || SUBSTR( A, -5 )` to get the first 5 characters of `B` (right-padded with spaces if required) concatenated with the last 5 characters of `A`.

For example:

```sql
SELECT A,
       B,
       RPAD( B, 5, ' ' ) || SUBSTR( A, -5 ) AS masked_value
FROM   table_name
```

With the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, B ) AS
SELECT 1234567890, 'SAM'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2345678912, 'HELLO'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7364557382, 'MORNING' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
>          A | B       | MASKED_VALUE
> ---------: | :------ | :-----------
> 1234567890 | SAM     | SAM  67890  
> 2345678912 | HELLO   | HELLO78912  
> 7364557382 | MORNING | MORNI57382
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a75c41f17302d7930c8102c4fad90fb)*